# Can I let the client stream the content from Spotify in a browser based player?

Tags: spotify

Couldn't find anything on Google about that topic, so I'm asking here. 
I had an idea for a web based Spotify player (not like the offical one) and I would like to know if it's possible to let the client (user) stream the content from Spotify instead of my server (app). Would be pretty expensive if my server would have to stream the data and to send it to the client :-/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no web library that you can use for streaming content from Spotify. The closest is the [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/) but that is a widget that remote controls Spotify from the desktop client or Spotify's web player.

You are limited to use the 30 seconds previews, or use the Android or iOS SDK if you were to build a mobile version of your site. The SDKs allow full playback for Spotify premium users.

There is a [feature request for fetching full tracks on Spotify's Web API GitHub repo](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/57) that you can watch or add comments to.

Comment: Well deserved bounty, Sir! Thanks!